# CodeIgniter, Order by number of rows in a separate joined table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 4 tables that link together...

Firstly the **hotels** table

- hotel_id
- town_id
- hotel_name

Then the **towns** table:

- town_id
- region_id
- town_name

Then the **regions** table:

- region_id
- country_id
- region_name

Finally the **countries** table

- country_id
- country_name

What I need to do is list the towns in order of how many hotels there are within that town.

The reason I have included the regions table and the countries table is because, when displaying that town, I need to display the country it's from. This can only be obtained via the regions table..

Therefore using the active records in CodeIgniter I have done this so far:

```
$this->db->join('regions','towns.town_region_id = regions.region_id');
$this->db->join('countries','regions.region_country_id = countries.country_id');
$query = $this->db->get('towns');

foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
     echo "<li>";
     echo "$row->town_name, $row->country_name";
     echo "</li>";
}
```

This outputs:

- London, United Kingdom
- Washington, United States
- New York, United States
- Moscow, Russia
- etc, etc

Each one of these cities have hotels in them. All I need now is to order them by how many hotels there are in each town..

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('t.*,c.*,COUNT(h.hotel_id) AS nhotels');
$this->db->from('towns t');
$this->db->join('hotels h','h.town_id = t.town_id');
$this->db->join('regions r','t.town_region_id = r.region_id');
$this->db->join('countries c','r.region_country_id = c.country_id');
$this->db->group_by('t.town_id');
$this->db->order_by("nhotels",'DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

which will produce the following query:

```
SELECT `t`.*, `c`.*, COUNT(h.hotel_id) AS nhotels
FROM (`towns` t)
   JOIN `hotels` h
      ON `h`.`town_id` = `t`.`town_id`
   JOIN `regions` r
      ON `t`.`town_region_id` = `r`.`region_id`
   JOIN `countries` c
      ON `r`.`region_country_id` = `c`.`country_id`
GROUP BY `t`.`town_id`
ORDER BY `nhotels` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I get this error: "Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause" Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: yaa, i've forgot thegroup by, sorry. Now it's fixed

Comment: Ahh! It works! However, it is not retrieving $row->country_name.. It says it's an "Undefined property"??

Comment: weird, the query should retrieve all town's and country's table columns. Did you tried the SQL query directly in mysql?

Comment: hmm, I just tried it then.. It seems to be grabbing all the correct data (including the country_name). So I'm confused to why it's not working?

Comment: try to `print_r($query)` in php

Comment: print_r($query) gives me.... CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #34 [result_id] => Resource id #56 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 2 [row_data] => )

Comment: print_r($query->result()); gives me.....    Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [town_id] => 2443 [town_region_id] => 33 [town_name] => Torquay [seo_town_name] => torquay [town_postcode] => TQ1 2PL [town_latitude] => [town_longitude] => [town_description] => Torquay [town_meta_keywords] => torquay [town_active] => 1 [nhotels] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [town_id] => 13602 [town_region_id] => 22 [town_name] => Newquay [seo_town_name] => newquay [town_postcode] => [town_latitude] => [town_longitude] => [town_description] => [town_meta_keywords] => [town_active] => 1 [nhotels] => 1 ) )

Comment: seems like you did not select the country table, copy the first php statement of my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   hotels.town_id, 
   count(hotels.hotel_id) from hotels AS hotels_count,
   towns.town_name
FROM
    hotels,
LEFT JOIN
    towns ON hotels.town_id = towns.town_id
GROUP BY hotels.town_id
ORDER BY hotels_count DESC;
```